# SSRS Matrix Grouping Vertically to keep headers in same column? Is it not possible?

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

using SSRS 2008 R2 here.

I've been able to get a similar layout to work with a regular tablix, where I get each group header to fall on top of each other in the same column by adding a row within that group, however I need to use a Matrix because of a dynamic column (month below).  When I try to add another row, it only adds a row where the monthly data starts, not in the headers.  So the headers stay in their each column.  In trying to keep the example as easy as possible, I'm trying to do something like this (Store theme).

```
STORE NAME   |     MONTHS
STATE        |     SALES
TOWN(S)      |     SALES
```

which woudl look something like this in a Matrix

```
WALMART        JAN       FEB      MARCH   etc....
TEXAS        | 3000      2000     6000
HOUSTON      | 1000      500      2500
AUSTIN       | 2000      1500     3500
```

I've only been able to produce something like this where each group is a seperate column:

```
STORE   |  STATE |  CITY    |  JAN   |  FEB   |  MAR  |
WALMART |  TEXAS |  HOUSTON |  1000  |  500   |  2500 |
                 |  AUSTIN  |  2000  |  1500  |  3500 |
```

Again, I've been able to get a regular Tablix formatted like this, but a Matrix I'm struggling with.  Can anyone help me on how to do this?  Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using a tablix/matrix and adding some special grouping settings.

1. Add a tablix with the `City` field in Row Groups pane:
   [image]
2. Right click the `City` group, select `Add Group` / `Parent Group`. Choose State and set Add a Group Header
   [image]
3. Delete the left most column (State column added in the previous step).
   [image]
   Note the group is still present.
4. Right click the STATE group and add a `Parent Group` as step 2. In this case choose `STORENAME`
   [image]
5. Again delete the left most column (Store Name column added in the previous step)
6. You will get the following tablix.

[image]

7. Delete the first row

[image]

8. Set the Fields using the Row Group hierarchy order. `STORENAME/STATE/CITY`
   [image]
9. Right click the first cell in the next column and add a group / Column Group / Parent Group. Choose MONTH in group by.
   [image]
10. Delete the first row.
11. Set `SUM(Fields!Sales.Value)` in the next cells in the same column.

After these steps you will get a tablix like this in design window.

[image]

It should produce:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much!  I didn't know about this method.  The only step I wasn't sure about was #8 in your post.  I assume that just meant to "set" the field names in the proper order? - there wasn't a way to do it through the gui which did anything other than just plugging the column names in.  Either way, fantastic response and highly appreciated!!  Cheers

Comment: @Jay, you are welcome. Maybe I was not clear enough, I mean use each field in the right cell. So the first cell expression should be `=Fields!STORENAME.Value` the second should be  `=Fields!STATE.Value` and third should be `=Fields!CITY.Value`, like you say you can drop and drag the fields to each cell as well. There are several ways to set a cell value, I say "set" and you can use any to link a cell with a field value.

Comment: Great thanks for the clarification.  That is what I assumed (and did) but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.  Thanks again